# ssl certificate for server and clients

Tags: ssl, certificate, xmpp

We have a XMPP server using SSL certificates (for both the server and the clients).

We use a self-signed CA to sign those certificates. Now we want to stop using that self-signed CA, but we have no idea how to replace those certificates to ones signed by an authority like Digicert or GlobalSign, since we don't know what to buy to do the same we usually do (we usually just create a public key, then a request and we sign it using the self-signed CA, and then voila, we have a certificate ready for the client to use)

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> we usually just create a public key, then a request and we sign it using the self-signed CA, and then voila, we have a certificate ready for the client to use)

The process is the same as for a Certificate Authority, with the difference you probably have to pay for the certificate

1. **generate a key pair**,private and public. (Not only the public)
2. Generate a **Certificate Signing Request** including the public key, some data about the certificate as Common Name, and sign it with the private key.
3. Send the CSR to the Certificate Authority
4. The CA  validates the CSR, builds the certificate and signs it with its private key
5. Finally the CA sends you the certificate